# Authorization in a multi-tenant web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

We have a multi-tenant application. Currently, the tenant is specified with every request as a route parameter:

```
GET api/Companies/3/Assets
GET api/Companies/5/Groups
```

The user is authenticated the normal way, but the authorization logic then happens in the `Controller`, not in an `IAuthorizationFilter`. As you can imagine, this causes a lot of duplicate code. I have thought of two alternatives, and I'm not sure which one to implement:

#### Move the company id to the access token

Pros:

- Simple to implement, only requires changing how the access token is issued
- Company id does not have to be specified in the route

Cons:

- Operations across multiple tenants are more complicated, and require two access tokens
- A user may follow a link to a resource, but be logged in with the wrong tenant

#### Update the AuthenticationFilter and AuthorizationFilter to look at the route

Pros:

- All the existing endpoints will continue to work as expected
- If a user follows a link, they don't have to log out and back in to the right company

Cons:

- The authentication filter will be performing some authorization, because it can't make claims about the user's permissions within the company without first verifying that the user belongs to that company
- Company id has to be specified in every route

Which of these two alternatives is normally used, and why?

Comment: I have a similar issue. In your case I can't understand a basic issue. Do you have the same usernames (associated to different phisical users) across tenants? Do you trust the client declared tenant (in a cookie or in request)?

Comment: Yes, we have the same usernames across tenants. We do not trust the client declared tenant id in the request; if we shift it to the access token then we can trust it, but we can't perform operations that need access to multiple tenants

Comment: We ended up moving the company id to the access token, since the only operations that required access across multiple tenants were administrative tasks, such as moving a resource from one tenant to another, or searching for a resource by serial number without knowing which tenant it belongs to.